# Difference between different kinds of sums of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say that we have linear subspaces $V$ and $W$ of $Y$.

What is the difference between the following sets:

1. $V+W$
2. $V\cup W$
3. $V\oplus W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the direct sum $V⊕W$ is a special case of the sum $V+W$ when the intersection of $V$ and $W$ is the zero subspace.

$V \cup W$ is a subset of $V + W$, for $v \in V$ can be written as $v = v+0 \in V+W$ and $w \in W$ can be written as $w = 0+w \in V+W$.

Note that $V \cup W$ need not be a subspace and the subset relation is possibly proper. Consider $V$ and $W$ as the x- and the y-axis as subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $(1,0),(0,1) \in V \cup W$ but (1,1) is outside $V \cup W$.

Answer (score 1):

$V + W$ is just the set $\{ v + w \mid v \in V, w \in W \}$.

$V \cup W = \{ y \mid y \in V \text{ or } y \in W \}$, i.e., $V \cup W$ is basically the set of vectors of $V$ and $W$ put into one set.  This is not necessarily a subspace. (Why?)

$V \oplus W$ is the direct sum of $V$ and $W$, and this is a subspace.  $V \oplus W$ is the same as $V + W$, except that we use the $\oplus$ notation when $V \cap W = \{ 0 \}$, i.e., the only vector they have in common is the $0$ vector.  We use this notation because every possible sum is unique.  That is, if we know $v_{1} \neq v_{2}$ in $V$ and $w_{1} \neq w_{2}$ in $W$, then $v_{1} + w_{1} \neq v_{2} + w_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is the linear space spanned by $V$ and $W$. It contains all vectors of $V$ and $W$, and also all vectors of the form $v + w$, where $v \in V$ and $w \in W$. This is a vector space. Example: If $V$ is the $xy$-plane and $W$ is the $yz$-plane in $\Bbb R^3$, then $V + W = \Bbb R^3$.
2. This is the union of the two linear subspaces, which means that it contains all elements from $V$ and $W$, but not $v + w$, unless $(v+w)$ happens to be in either $V$ or $W$. Unless either $V \subseteq W$ or $W \subseteq V$, this is *not* a vector space for this reason. With the example $V$ and $W$ above, $V\cup W$ consist of all vectors where either the first or the last coordinate is equal to $0$.
3. This is the set of vectors of the form $(v, w)$, where $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. This is a vector space. With the $V$ and $W$ as above again, one vector in $V \oplus W$ is $\big((1, 1, 0), (0, 2, 3)\big)$. This is the only one of these constructions which doesn't really care whether $V$ and $W$ have any vectors in common, or even if they are subspaces of the same space.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering what you mean when you say the direct sum "is the only one of these constructions which doesn't really care whether $V$ and $W$ have any vectors in common."  I thought we use the $\oplus$ notation precisely when they have only the $0$ vector in common.

Comment: You could take two vector spaces that have nothing in common, like $\Bbb C$ and the space $M_{2\times3}(\Bbb R)$ of real $2\times3$ matrices, and you can form the direct sum $\Bbb C\oplus M_{2\times3}(\Bbb R)$, where one vector is $$\left(1+2i,\left[\matrix{1&\pi&\ln4\\\sqrt{15}&e&-5}\right]\right)$$Also, $\Bbb R^2$ is written as the real numbers "to the second power" because it is $\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R$ (direct sum and direct product coincide for finitely many terms).

Comment: However, when $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of the same (finite dimensional) space, then $V+W\approx V\oplus W$ exactly when they only have the zero vector in common. Otherwise $V\oplus W$ is larger. Back to the example in my answer, this is so because $(0,1,0)+(0,0,0)=(0,0,0)+(0,1,0)$, but $\big((0,1,0),(0,0,0)\big)\neq\big((0,0,0),(0,1,0)\big)$.